# Export iMacro script into Python?

Tags: python, urllib, imacros, headless-browser

I need to automate a website but it needs to be headless and within python.
I can do what I need to do on that website with iMacros, but iMacros is unflexible.
I tried to understand what iMacros did and replicate via Selenium, Mechanize etc.
All the things I found however fail at passing javascript events.

This is the Login part in iMacros:

```
URL GOTO=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
FRAME NAME="main"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:j_security_check ATTR=ID:login-user CONTENT=myusername
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ACTION:j_security_check ATTR=ID:login-password CONTENT=mypassword
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ACTION:j_security_check ATTR=TXT:Login
```

I tried to understand this step and after a few tests I found urllib to be working:

```
#Step 1): Login Process
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen(main+welcome)
urllib2.urlopen(main+jsecurity,
 data=urllib.urlencode({'j_username':'myusername','j_password':'mypassword'}))
```

So the login works, the next part is where I get stuck (iMacros again):

```
FRAME NAME="main"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:menu-ES1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:ManageEventForm ATTR=ID:ES1_itemA CONTENT=000000
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:ManageEventForm ATTR=NAME:tab-idmain-settab-event.tabs.main;dispatch.setScopeEvent
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:ManageEventForm ATTR=ID:ES1_eventBuilder CONTENT=TEST
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:ManageEventForm ATTR=NAME:tab-idmain-settab-event.tabs.main;dispatch.setScopeEvent
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:TEST
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:ManageEventForm ATTR=ID:ES1_remarks CONTENT=<SP>TEST
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:ManageEventForm ATTR=ID:ES1_callbackRemark CONTENT=<SP>TEST
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:ManageEventForm ATTR=NAME:tab-idmain-settab-event.tabs.more;dispatch.setScopeEvent
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:ManageEventForm ATTR=ID:ES1_reportingUserTelephone CONTENT=TEST
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON FORM=NAME:ManageEventForm ATTR=NAME:LogEvent
```

I simply don't know how to copy what imacros did here and where to start in this step...
It´s basically 4 forms that need info and then LogEvent (submit button).

Does anyone have ideas on how to proceed here? Im new to programming Im sorry if my question is "nooby" but I´ve spent 3 weeks on google to find out about mechanize,selenium, imacros (which worked in some way I guess) etc...

I´d appreciate any help

Comment: Have you tried to wrap imacros code into string and play it? http://wiki.imacros.net/Python

Comment: Hello and Thank you for your answer, yes I did try it but the problem is that it opens up another program which is not what I was looking for :(

Comment: Hi. Do you know how to interpret these commands in iMacros? Have you tried looking into basic python functions to check for solution?

Comment: I implemented imacros to the python program that I wrote, now it calls the macro after a certain condition has been met. I just whish i could do what Imacros does within python itself or with a module like selenium/mechanize